# How to keep track of string index for Pushdown Automaton?

Tags: pushdown-automaton

i have to construct this PDA, but i am confused on how is possible to keep track a string index xi and yi? thanks in advance

> > Construct a PDA that accepts { x#y | x, y in {0, 1}* such that x ≠ y and xi = yi for
> >     some i, 1 ≤ i ≤ min(|x|, |y|) }.

Comment: Don't just put your homework here and expect people to it for you...

Comment: i did not expect the answer from anyone. i just need hint on how is it possible to know the index while only got 1 stack to work with.